# Why numpy and pandas both the library give different output if we calculate standard deviation?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

Refer to the code shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
fir_salary = [10000,20000,15000,20000,15000,25000]
df=pd.DataFrame(fir_salary)

print(np.std(fir_salary))
print(df.std()) <-- Return different output
```

I have referred to the thread [Different Standard Deviation in Pandas and Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58568375/different-standard-deviation-in-pandas-and-numpy) which talks about the degree of freedom.

But I need help to understand what exactly is the degree of freedom. Does it have to do anything with sample and population standard deviation calculations?

Comment: Refer to link https://www.aboutdatablog.com/post/why-computing-standard-deviation-in-pandas-and-numpy-yields-different-results if this helps.

Comment: There is also this question which has a good explanation and further links in one of the answers: [Different std in pandas vs numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984178/different-std-in-pandas-vs-numpy)

Comment: They use different defaults for the degrees of freedom